# Angular 6: Add java script library like this "https://www.npmjs.com/package/url-regex"

Tags: javascript, npm, angular6

Need help
I want to this URL validator in my angular application
https://www.npmjs.com/package/url-regex

Can someone please guide me how can I include in my angular

Thanks and regards
Sudeep Singh Rawat

Comment: Where should i put this line of code ha?? const urlRegex = require('url-regex'); in my directive or  or my class

Answer (score 0):

Sorry  i don't know about  much about the angular and web pack and how import statement work so i got confused 
import urlRegex  from 'url-regex';
answer was simple

Answer (score 0):

All you need to do is install the package `$ npm install --save url-regex`

After this in the place you want to use the Regex you need to import the module:

```
const urlRegex = require('url-regex');
```

An then use the variable urlRegex the place you need to test the url:
Ex:

```
urlRegex().test('http://github.com foo bar');
```

But this is on server side (nodejs server);

In Angular 6 you have many ways to do it but not with this library.
And to be honest i have no idea if there is any library to  be installed that makes this.
But if you dont find any i think best way will be through reactive forms and validators.

https://angular.io/api/forms

You are able to create your directive, where you define which validator you need and patterns
And yes here Angular already have RegExp:
More info here : https://angular.io/api/forms/PatternValidator